# Default props in theme configuration seems not to work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

it's the first time I'm using [Material UI](https://mui.com/) and I'm having some problems using `createTheme`.

My goal is to remove the horizontal padding for each `Container` so I decided to put this configuration in the `theme` file:

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import "@fontsource/roboto";

export const COLORS = {
  beige: "#bfafae",
  white: "#FFFFFF"
};

const { beige, white } = COLORS;

const palette = {
  primary: { main: beige },
  common: { white: white }
};

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Noto Sans", "Arial", "sans-serif"].join(","),
    fontSize: 16
  },
  palette,
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1536
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiContainer: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableGutters: true
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: beige,
          paddingLeft: 0,
          paddingRight: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default theme;
```

I use it in this way:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container sx={{ height: "100%", minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Container maxWidth="sm" sx={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>
        app
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Result:

[image]

Instead, if I set `disableGutters` in the components, it works:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container disableGutters sx={{ height: "100%", minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Container disableGutters maxWidth="sm" sx={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>
        app
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Result:

[image]

I'm using Typescript but it's the same without it.

What I'm wrong?

---

`index.js`:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

Comment: Have you wrapped the App in a `ThemeProvider`? [Docs theming](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-provider).

Comment: @mariusflorescu thanks for the reply. For sure, I edited the main message

Comment: Seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-forked-8rhz7g?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

add `CssBaseline` component, it is a collection of CSS reset styles.

```
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the theme, your palette is not being read write, and everything after it doesn't work as well, it should be something like:

```
const theme = createTheme({
typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Noto Sans", "Arial", "sans-serif"].join(","),
    fontSize: 16
  },
  **palette: palette,**
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1536
    }
  },
```